# TFS / VS 2012 RC - where is VSSConverter.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vssconverter

I am setting up a VM with a brand new install of TFS 2012 using the RC just released. This is the first time we have tried to use TFS in my company and I need to upgrade some SourceSafe databases. I've also installed the RC for Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Edition (everything but the MFC foundation classes) but I still can't find the VSSConverter.exe tool.

According to Google it's supposed to be in the Common7\Ide folder, but is nowhere to be seen. Admittedly the only internet links I can find at the moment are for VS2010 so they may be out of date, but I have scanned the entire C drive and still can't find VSSConverter.exe

ps. I know there is a "download and install VSS converter" link in the TFS Admin Console but that just takes me to the Microsoft home page! : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx

Comment: You wrote "You will, however, need to install a 2010 instance just to run the tool". TFS instance or VS instance? I guess executing VSSconverter from VS2010(with SP1+GDR) connected to TFS 2012 is not an option, is it? Dan

Answer (score 5):

VSSConverter is moving away from being a standalone tool and - as you noted - moving to be a part of the TFS Admin Console.

Unfortunately, the VSS -> TFS conversion experience did not ship as part of the TFS 2012 RC.  It will instead be included in the released TFS 2012.

In the meantime, the VSSConverter that was included as part of TFS 2010 *will* properly migrate to a TFS 2012 instance.  You will, however, need to install a 2010 instance just to run the tool.

If you do not require the full history, you could simply check-out your VSS databases and then check them into TFS.  Another alternative is to install TFS 2010 and use VSSConverter to that database, then perform an in-place upgrade to TFS 2012.

Comment: Also, feel free to send me an email (you can find it on my profile) if you'd like me to try to find out if there are any beta or prerelease versions of the VSS converter tool available.

Comment: OK, thanks Edward. I'll send you an email, it would be worth trying a beta version on our VSS database, though it looks like it is worth waiting for the final release of TFS 2012 before setting up the final environment (I was expecting the RC to be pretty much finished in all respects, to be honest). I want it to be as clean as possible, so upgrading from TFS 2010 is not a desirable path.

Comment: +1 - Note the VSS Upgrade tool is about to ship. It will offer a wizard with a first class experience (similar to TFS Upgrade).  The admin console has a forward link that will point to the downloadable tool when it's released.